# Angular Production Build Error in Team City :

Tags: angular, build, teamcity

We are facing Angular Build Error in Team City when doing the Production build.
Please help.

Project Using : Angular 7

Please find the attached error log image.

[Build Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWRzP.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's look like node version issue, upgrade your node version, or just re-install node with latest/compatible version with angular 7.